# how to call predefined method inside tabs() in latest jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am upgrading jquery UI from 1.9 to 1.12 in my project. I want to call predefined method that is defined in a js file. In old version, it is working as

```
var temp = $('#' + this.id).tabs('addData', '#' + this.id + '-' + this.tabCount);
```

here `addData` is defined in different js file as plugin that I am including in my project

When I upgraded it to latest version, it is not calling `addData` method and giving error 'no such method 'addData' for tabs widget instance for the same code.

How to replace this code in jquery ui latest version so that my website can run smoothly. I have tried

```
var temp = $('#' + this.id).bind('addData', '#' + this.id + '-' + this.tabCount);
```

bit it didn't work. I want to call `addData` method

Comment: Why would you think that `bind()` would be the solution? That's for binding event handlers.

Comment: I don't see `addData` in the 1.9 documentation. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: I just checked the 1.9 source code, and can't find the word `addData` anywhere in it.

Comment: I suspect this is something you added yourself, you need to re-add it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. `addData` is not included as a regular jQuery UI method. You reported that it was added as part of a Plugin. If you are seeing `no such method 'addData'`, this would suggest that the plugin is not yet loaded.

Comment: addData is a predefined method in other javascript file. It does not have any relation with jquery ui. I just want to load/call this method  using tabs() function. In old version tabs() is working but now it showing 'no such method 'addData' for tabs widget instance' @Barmar

Comment: That's not how jQuery UI works, you can't call random methods like that.

Comment: @Abhishek where is the `addData` method defined in your older version? Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example so that we can properly help out.